# utag is not defined in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

trying to load utag.js from static resource in lightning component with following tag.

```
      <ltng:require scripts="/resource/UTAG1/utag/utag.js" afterScriptsLoaded = "{!c.afterScriptsLoaded}" />
```

in afterScriptsLoaded calling utag.view method.

```
   var utag_data = {
        userGuid : "", // 
                   l1 : "", // 
                   l2 : "", // 
                   l3 : "", // 
                   l4 : "", // 
                   l5 : "", // 
                   l6 : "", // 
                   l7 : "", // 
                   l8 : "", // 
                   event : "", //
                   environment : "", //
                   user_id : usrid, 
    }
    console.log('utag_data---'+utag_data);

    try{
        utag.view(utag_data);
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
```

utag.view(utag_data);here ended up with utag is not defined error. Please do needful.

Comment: Where did you get utag.js and what are you trying to achieve with this library ?

Comment: utag is a tealiumiq javascript library which is used to track few details from salesforce as part of omniture adobe analytics.

Answer (score 0):

I think the property is not shared with lightning component . This doc might be helpful : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_share_code.htm .

Comment: Thanks for the response. I already referred this.As this is external javascript, I am not sure how to apply this to utag.js file. Do you have any idea how to apply this on external js files.